# Font awesome not showing icons

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, static, font-awesome

I'm deploying a django application that collects the static files from a S3 bucket. Yesterday I managed to fix this problem before because there was a CORS problem and icons were displayed properly. Today they appear as blank squares again even if I haven't changed anything (I don't receive any problems in the chrome console so it can't be the cors problem).

If I use the font awesome CDN it works fine but I'd like to know what can be the problem and keep using my static file.

Many thanks.

Comment: Are there definitely no 404s for anything showing up in the Chrome console?

Comment: Hard to help you if you don't check the reference in your html. Are the fonts loaded? Do you get a 404?